# Sharing unopened files rather than getting local copy of everything

Tags: version-control, perforce

I'd like to know if there are any revision control systems such that, when user checks-out/gets/creates a workarea, it will create symbolic links for the files, rather than a local copy of everything. Once we "edit" a file, then it will replace the symbolic link with a local copy.

To make it more clear, let's say we have a repository like this:

```
proj/
    data/
        big_data.csv
    src/
        script.py
```

Users are mostly working on script.py, but data folder is huge in size. If every user keeps a local copy of big_data.csv, it consumes lots of disk space. If the revision control system keeps a copy of every version of every file, then all we need is a link to it. Users don't need to hold a local copy, unless they have to edit that file.

```
proj/
    data/
        @big_data.csv -> /depot/proj/data/big_data.csv#5
    src/
        script.py
```

So which revision control tools have a feature like this? Is it possible to get something similar in perforce?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know how Perforce works, but in a DVCS such as Git, if a user clones a big file, that file will be copied to the user’s local filesystem. The act of cloning will not take up any more space on the server, so I’m not sure what your issue is. (Also, investigate copy-on-write filesystems.)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a symlink checked into a Perforce depot, and it can point wherever you like (I assume in this case you'd have a read-only shared network filer that the file lives on), but when you `p4 edit` it you'll just be editing where the symlink points.

I can envision a way you'd set this up in Perforce with streams (you could do it with classic branches and template clients too, but streams make it a lot easier).

You'd have one stream (let's call it `dw`) where `big_data` is the actual file, and one stream (let's call it `dr`) where `big_data` is the symlink, and `big_data` is specified as an `isolate` Path so that changes won't merge between the two.

There's a background script (maybe a `change-commit` trigger on `dw/big_data`) that writes each revision of `dw/big_data` to the filer as a unique read-only file, and then edits and submits `dr/big_data` to create a symlink revision that points to the filer revision.  Hence a user syncing `dr/big_data` will get (via symlink) the matching revision of `dw/big_data`.  `dr/big_data` is made read-only (via `p4 protect`) to all normal users to make sure nobody accidentally edits it; it needs to be strictly managed by the script that ties it to the filer.

So users who don't want to edit `big_data` use the `dr` stream; they can sync `big_data` to whatever revision they want, and it behaves normally, but they can't edit it.  Other files in the stream (e.g. `script.py`) are normal files and they can edit them normally.

If a user wants to edit `big_data`, they do `p4 switch dw` and everything resyncs (for most of the files this is probably a no-op) and now `big_data` is a normal editable file.  When they submit a new revision to it, the trigger fires and a second later there's a matching `dr/big_data` symlink, so users in the `dr` branch will see the change when they sync.  (The one symlink rev per revision is so that you still get the benefits of versioning; `big_data` ONLY updates when you sync to the new symlink rev.  If you didn't want this behavior you could just ignore keeping the file in Perforce and symlink straight to the filer and edit it there directly, but I assume you want actual version control on it.)  Once they're done editing, they're free to `p4 switch dr` and go back to the read-only symlink (the head revision of which will now reference the  revision they just submitted).

Whether `dr` is a parent of `dw` or vice versa, and how this fits into the rest of your codeline hierarchy, is left as an exercise for the reader -- it depends on whether you need to make edits to `big_data` in more than one codeline or whether having a linear "master" history of it is sufficient.